# If $p \equiv 1$ mod 4 is prime then there are 8 pairs $(a,b)$ s.t. $a^2+b^2 = p$

Tags: number-theory

I need help to show the above statement. I know that there is definitely a solution $(a,b)$ and I can take negatives to make 8 different pairs; but how do I show there are no more than these 8 pairs?

Also I need to prove the more general statement that there are $4(k+1)$ pairs s.t. $a^2+b^2 =p^k$

Thanks for your help and hints.

Comment: You need to know the basic facts about the ring of Gaussian integers. Search for Gaussian integers for details.

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaL_Cb42WyY) is a nice video by 3blue1brown, where this result is explained and used, and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00w8gu2aL-w) is a mathologer video doing the exact same thing.

Comment: You can find out the details about Gaussian integers here: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/math5230f12/handouts/Zinotes.pdf

Use it to prove the above statement.

Comment: Thanks for all your help