# Prove that $a^2+b^2=p$ has a unique solution $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}^2$ with $a\le b$, where $p\equiv 1\pmod4$ is prime.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, unique-factorization-domains, gaussian-integers

I am trying to prove the following:

> Consider $p$, a prime natural number with $p\equiv 1\pmod4$. Show
> that the equation $a^2 + b^2 = p$ has a unique solution $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}_{≥0}$, up to swapping $a$ and $b$.

I know if $p\equiv 1(\bmod4)$ then $p = (a + bi)(a − bi)$ is a prime factorisation, which I think gets me part of the way there, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Proof-Wiki shows a nice proof using the method of infinite descent. First, the existence is proven, the the uniqueness. That this does not work for primes $4k+3$ is clear because of simple modular arithmetic (modulo $4$)

Comment: Please see the comments of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3567889/if-p-equiv-1-mod-4-is-prime-then-there-are-8-pairs-a-b-s-t-a2b2-p). Maybe useful.

Answer (score 4):

If we have two ways to write $p$ as a sum of two squares:
$$
p=a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2
$$
then that would give rise to two prime factorizations
$$
p=(a+bi)(a-bi)=(c+di)(c-di)
$$
But the fundamental theorem of arithmetic is still valid in the Gaussian integers. So these two factorizations must be the same, up to order, and factors of $i$. Thus $a^2,b^2$ must be the same two squares as $c^2,d^2$ (albeit possibly not in the same order).

Comment: The question is to prove (part of) unique factorization in $\Bbb Z[i]$. You shouldn't use what should  be proved as argument in your proof.

Answer (score 0):

The uniqueness part follows from the identity
$$a^2c^2-b^2d^2=(a^2+b^2)c^2-b^2(c^2+d^2)\,.$$
Thus, if $a^2+b^2=p$ and $c^2+d^2=p$, then $a^2c^2\equiv b^2d^2\pmod{p}$, or $ac\equiv \pm bd\pmod{p}$.

If $ac\equiv +bd\pmod{p}$, then note that
$$p^2=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2\,.$$
Show that this means $ac=bd$, and so $(a,b)=(d,c)$.  If $ac\equiv -bd\pmod{p}$, then note that
$$p^2=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2\,.$$
Show that this means $ad=bc$, and so $(a,b)=(c,d)$.

The existence part is done by first observing that $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ has a solution $x\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Now, consider the set $$S:=\big\{0,1,2,\ldots,\lfloor\sqrt{p}\rfloor\big\}\times\big\{0,1,2,\ldots,\lfloor\sqrt{p}\rfloor\big\}\,.$$  Note that $$|S|=\big(\lfloor\sqrt{p}\rfloor+1\big)^2>\big(\sqrt{p}\big)^2=p\,.$$  Ergo, by the Pigeonhole Principle, there are two distinct pairs $(a_1,b_1)$ and $(a_2,b_2)$ in $S$ such that $$a_1x-b_1\equiv a_2x-b_2\pmod{p}\,.$$  Let $a:=|a_1-a_2|$ and $b:=|b_1-b_2|$. We have that
$$a^2+b^2= (a_1-a_2)^2+(b_1-b_2)^2\equiv (b_1-b_2)^2\left(x^2+1\right)\equiv 0\pmod{p},$$
and $0\leq a,b\leq \lfloor\sqrt{p}\rfloor<\sqrt{p}$.  Since $a$ and $b$ cannot be both zero (otherwise $(a_1,b_1)=(a_2,b_2)$), we have $$0<a^2+b^2<2p\,.$$
As $a^2+b^2$ is divisible by $p$, $a^2+b^2=p$ must hold.